# HTML5 Drag and Drop doesnt work in specifc cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Can you please let us know if there are there any special cases where HTML5 drop event doest fire.
I see a strange issue with drop event of HTML5, which I stuck with. I am sure I must be doing something wrong here. The scenario here is.. Here is the drop zone I defined. This code works Perfectly fine when I drag elements, even files from desktop. 
But I have one particular widget in our application which has divs, table-td's with draggable set to true, though Im able to drag these elements, the drop event doesnt get fired when I move this dragged element or drop the dragged element on the drop zone.

```
<div class="drop">drop here</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
 {

    $('.drop').on('drop dragdrop',function(event){
    alert('dropped');
});
$('.drop').on('dragenter',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('drop now').css('background','blue');
})
$('.drop').on('dragleave',function(event){
    $(this).html('drop here').css('background','red');
})
$('.drop').on('dragover',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
})


 });
</script>
```

Comment: seems to be working fine for me. please be more specific as to what exactly you are dragging when the drop doesnt fire?

Comment: @mkaatman this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/6La6vc2x/) seems to disagree with you...

Comment: @mkaatman - Though we need to pass the event, the problem here is the function doesnt get fired at all.